# Automate a click to make a collapse link change from less info to more info

Tags: javascript, html

I an trying use automation to click on a "More Details" link on a popup to show more info but the link doesn't have any id associated with it.
When I inspect the link in Chrome console the it appears to be the "href="#myCollapse" line below in the associated element.
I dont know js at all really but have tried a number of things along the lines of document.getElementById('#myCollapse').click();... and tried to use child of id="popup-content".

```js
<div id="popup-content">
        <span id="overlayAddress">SCOTTISH PARLIAMENT  1 HORSE WYND OLD TOWN </span><br>
        <span id="overlayTown">EDINBURGH</span><br>
        <span id="overlayPostCode">EH99 1SP</span>
        <br>
            <a href="#myCollapse" data-bs-toggle="collapse" class="collapsed" aria-expanded="false">More Details</a>
            <div class="collapse" id="myCollapse" style="">
             <label style="color:white;"><b>UPRN :&nbsp;</b></label><span id="overlayuprn">906423108</span><br> 
             <label style="color:white;"><b>POSTAL TOWN :&nbsp;</b></label><span id="overlayPostTown">EDINBURGH</span><br>
             <label style="color:white;"><b>CUSTODIAN :&nbsp;</b></label><span id="overlayCustodian">City of Edinburgh</span><br>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the following selector:

```js
document.querySelector('#popup-content a[href="#myCollapse"]').click()
```